# Python Nltk: ngrams filtration

Tags: python, nltk

i have this text and i want to know how to do it as i tried many ways to filter the ngrams

```
>>> bigrams_list = ('Hi', 'ya'), ('See', 'you'), ('My', 'name'), ...;
>>> trigrams_list = ('It', 'is', 'fine'), ('See', 'you', 'tomorrow'), ('My','surname', 'is')]
>>> fourgrams_list = ('It', 'is', 'fine', 'thanks'), ('Bla', 'bla', 'bla', 
'bla'), ('Attention','to', 'the', 'words'), ....
```

So from the new trigrams list i've to exclude "('See', 'you', 'tomorrow')", 
from the new fourgrams i've to exclude "('It', 'is', 'fine', 'thanks')" and so on. 
any suggestion

Comment: ...what? Is there a question in there?

Comment: exclude the ngrams that appear in a lower list with one additional 
token at the end (ex. the president of (trigram), the president of the (four-gram)

Comment: *"i tried many ways"* - could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the one of those many ways that worked best, and explain how precisely it could be better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289553/python-nltk-ngrams-filtering-and-excluding here is another question
can you please take a look in this question which is related to the this one also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `list[:-1]` to check through the trigrams for bigrams:

```
>>> bigrams = [('hi', 'ya'), ('see', 'you'), ('my', 'name')]
>>> trigrams = [('it', 'is', 'fine'), ('see', 'you', 'tomorrow'), ('my', 'name', 'is')]
>>> fourgrams = [('it', 'is', 'fine', 'thanks'), ('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'), ('what', 'sort', 'of', 'question'), ('is', 'this', 'any', 'ways'), ('please', 'read', 'SO', 'FAQ'), ('before', 'posting', 'questions', 'here')]
>>> filtered_trigrams = [i for i in trigrams if i[:-1] not in bigrams]
>>> filtered_trigrams
[('it', 'is', 'fine')]
>>> filtered_fourgrams = [i for i in fourgrams if i[:-1] not in trigrams]
>>> filtered_fourgrams
[('blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'), ('what', 'sort', 'of', 'question'), ('is', 'this', 'any', 'ways'), ('please', 'read', 'SO', 'FAQ'), ('before', 'posting', 'questions', 'here')]
```

Unless the bigrams and trigrams are from different corpora, it is not realistic to filter anything. Because all trigrams from the same text will include its bigrams and so on and so forth for Ngrams and N-1grams:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> text = """hi ya. see you tomorrow. it is fine, thank you. my name is blah blah blah. attention to the words..."""
>>> list(ngrams(word_tokenize(text), 2))
[('hi', 'ya.'), ('ya.', 'see'), ('see', 'you'), ('you', 'tomorrow.'), ('tomorrow.', 'it'), ('it', 'is'), ('is', 'fine'), ('fine', ','), (',', 'thank'), ('thank', 'you.'), ('you.', 'my'), ('my', 'name'), ('name', 'is'), ('is', 'blah'), ('blah', 'blah'), ('blah', 'blah.'), ('blah.', 'attention'), ('attention', 'to'), ('to', 'the'), ('the', 'words'), ('words', '...')]
>>> bigrams = list(ngrams(word_tokenize(text), 2))
>>> trigrams = list(ngrams(word_tokenize(text), 3))
>>> fourgrams = list(ngrams(word_tokenize(text), 4))
>>> [i for i in trigrams if i[:-1] not in bigrams]
[]
>>> [i for i in fourgrams if i[:-1] not in trigrams]
[]
>>> [i for i in fourgrams if i[:-2] not in bigrams]
[]
>>> len([i for i in trigrams if i[:-1] in bigrams]) == len(trigrams)
True
```